# Increment an object count variable by one, every time one of the many object methods is invoked/called

Tags: javascript, object

Let's say we have the following object:

```
class Foo{
     constructor(){
          this.count = 0;
     }
     method1() { <does something> }
     method2() { <does something else> }
     method3() { <does something even more> }
}
```

Now obviously we can add the following line of code to EACH method and the count will update:

```
this.count++;
```

While I know it's only one line code one can say that it is a redundant line of code. So is there way that we can detect if an object method has been invoked, no matter which one it is, and then update the count?

Comment: Would you consider adding unnecessary code more or less "redundant" to just using `this.count++` in each method?

Comment: This is fairly simple example to illustrate the problem. But if there were more functions then it would be redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might iterate over a separate object of methods to add instead, and have them do `this.count++` first.

```js
class Foo{
     constructor(){
          this.count = 0;
     }
}
const methods = {
  method1() {
    console.log('m1');
  },
  method2() {
    console.log('m2');
  },
  method3() {
    console.log('m3');
  },
};
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(methods)) {
  Foo.prototype[key] = function(...args) {
    this.count++;
    value(...args);
  }
}

const f = new Foo();
f.method1();
f.method1();
f.method2();
console.log(f.count);
```

Comment: This is a cool answer! Junior coders should be aware, however, that you're adding complexity to debugging down the track, and generally avoid this sort of thing because while it makes writing it a few less lines of code now, it makes it really hard for the person who replaces you to figure out where that count comes from.

Comment: That's sick, thank you. And yes I agree that it does add a  bit of complexity, but at least in my case I'm not sharing the code with anyone. This question was posted purely to determine if it was even possible.